# Having trouble implementing a multiple image upload system in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload, laravel, laravel-4

in my web application, people can create posts. Alonng with these posts, they may upload multiple images. To do this, I have a posts table and an image table. Posts hasMany images, and an Image belongs to a post. Therefore, the images table has an image_path column and a post_id column. My trouble is getting the post_id. Because I cant get a post ID before the post has been uploaded, I can't set which post the image belongs to. Anyway, here is some code:

```
public function create(){

    $post = new Post;

    $post->title=Input::get('title');
    $post->body=Input::get('body');
    $post->category=Input::get('category');

    $post->save();

    $images = Input::file('images');

    foreach($images as $image) {

        $destinationPath = 'public/uploads/';
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();

        $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);

        $id=Auth::id();

        $file = new Image();
        $file->image_path = 'uploads/' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->description = '';
        $file->post_id=Input::get('post_id');

        $file->save();

}
```

What would be the best way to go about fixing this problem?

Comment: I think instead of taking input at create function you can just create a new entry as soon as the user clicks creation link, and redirect to `/posts/{id}/edit` after the creation process. When you pre-create the posts Laravel would insert `created_at` and `updated_at` columns by itself, and you can delete unneccessary posts let's say after a day or a week by listing the posts where `created_at` and `updated_at` columns are equal.

By that you can use ajax calls to upload images by drag and drop using `jquery-file-uploader` which is pretty easy to implement or just do `id` dependent things.

Answer (score 2):

Once you save the `Post` using `$post->save()` then you may get the id using:

```
// ...
$post->save();
/...

$file->post_id = $post->id;
```

You may try this instead:

```
// ...
$post->save();

$destinationPath = 'uploads/';
$images = Input::file('images');
foreach($images as $image) {
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $image->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    $file = new Image();
    $file->image_path = 'uploads/' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->description = '';
    $post->images->save($file);
}
```